# perl : how to split?

Tags: regex, perl, split, substr

I have a string `aa:bb::cc:yy:zz` which needs to be split in such a way that I have an array with `aa:bb::cc`, `yy`, `zz`. i.e. I want to create two substrings from last with `:` as delimiter and remaining as a element of an array. What's the best way to achieve this?

ex:

```
aa:bb::cc:yy:zz --> ['aa:bb::cc','yy','zz']

dd:ff:gg:dd:ee:ff:fg --> ['dd:ff:gg:dd:ee','ff','gg']
```

I store IP address:port:protocol as a key in a file , and splitting wiht ":" to get IP,port,proto back and things were working fine when IP address is limited to Ipv4.  Now I want to make it ported to Ipv6 in which case IP address contains ":" so I can't get proper IP address by splitting with ":".

Comment: It would be safer to store your `(IP,port)` pairs using the standardized `[IP address]:port` format. The `parse_hostport`/`format_hostport` in the [AnyEvent::Socket](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent::Socket) module are helpful to handle it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 'dd:ff:gg:dd:ee:ff:fg';
my @l = $x =~ /^(.*?):([^:]+):([^:]+)$/g;
dump @l;
```

**output:**

```
("dd:ff:gg:dd:ee", "ff", "fg")
```

Comment: Note that this will fail on 'two or less pairs' string, like 'dd:ff' or 'dd'

Comment: that's not a problem for me as I would expect miminum of 3 parameters.

Comment: THanks M42, perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

This code will correct handle situations when $string contains 2 or less pairs:

```
my $string = 'aa:bb::cc:yy:zz';
my @data = split /:/, $string;
if (@data > 2) {
    unshift @data, join ':', splice @data, 0, -2;
}

# $string = 'aa:bb::cc:yy:zz';
# @data contains ('aa:bb::cc', 'yy', 'zz')

# $string = 'aa:bb';
# @data contains ('aa', 'bb')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -wE '$_="aa:bb::cc:yy:zz"; say join "\n", split /:([^:]+):([^:]+)$/, $_;'
aa:bb::cc
yy
zz
```

**Update:** You did not mention this was meant to parse IP addresses. If it is, you would probably be better off trying to find a module on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/)

Comment: @kumar You are welcome. It's basically the same solution as M42.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do an overly aggressive [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) followed by a join. I think the result is much more readable when you're not using a complicated regex for the split. So:

```
my $string = 'aa:bb::cc:yy:zz';
my @split_string = split(/:/, $string);
my @result = (join(':', @split_string[0..scalar(@split_string)-3]), $split_string[-2], $split_string[-1]);
print join(', ', @result), "\n";
```

Gives you:

```
aa:bb::cc, yy, zz
```

You'd have to do some array bounds checking on `@split_string` before you start indexing it like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -e'$_="aa:bb::cc:yy:zz"; @f=/(.*):([^:]+):(.+)/; print "$_\n" for @f'
aa:bb::cc
yy
zz

$ perl -e'$_="dd:ff:gg:dd:ee:ff:fg"; @f=/(.*):([^:]+):(.+)/; print "$_\n" for @f'
dd:ff:gg:dd:ee
ff
fg
```